# Easily typing unicode letters to a HTML form

Tags: website, unicode

Is there a program or a key map that allows me to easily type mathematcial symbols and unicode letters such as [these symbols](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html) in a web form?

Maybe a keyboard mapping? An assitant program?

(What I'm doing now is, copy-pasting relevant symbols, which is far from convenient...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by hex code and <kbd>Space</kbd> work for you?

As demonstrated here, with Greek lambda, known from functional programming and lambda-calculus, hex code 03BB:

λ-calculus, see how I entered this below in a gif.

[image: entering lambda here in SO answer form and entering 'tilda a' via keyboard code]

FWIW: it works for me on Ubuntu since 10.04, it worked on Linux Mint and on Debian (which serves as a base for both). I've tried this someday on Mac OS and it worked too (no idea which version it was). Never tried on Windows.

Comment: symbols ≪ mnemonics, but it's nice. Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- *If* the stuff you put into the web form will be displayed as html, and
  *if* the form processing doesn't do any conversion/sanitizing, then you
  can type the html entities into your
  input text, e.g. `&Theta;` or
  `&prop;`. It will look ugly in the
  form input, but displayed as html, it
  should look like Θ and ∝.
- You can install a Greek keyboard
  layout and set an accelerator key
  combo for switching between
  keyboards, e.g. Shift+Alt. This will
  only help for the Greek letters,
  obviously.
- You can learn the Alt+Num shortcuts
  for the symbols you want. The problem
  with this is that unfortunately, very
  few the characters on the page you
  linked have Alt+Num shortcuts.

None of these options will work for every character, so you will still have to resort to copying and pasting in some cases, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: it's better than nothing, but nothing is not the only other option. I was hoping for a program that would make inserting unicode symbols easier.

Comment: Well, judging by the vast number of responses you received in the three months since you posted your question, 'nothing' does appear to be the only other option. You can hope for an easy way out all you want, but that doesn't mean it exists. "Don't let the best be the enemy of the good", as the saying goes.

Answer (score 0):

See this Autohotkey script:
http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44766

Comment: It's not a solution, but I can hack a solution using this function.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a program or a key map that allows me to easily type mathematcial symbols and unicode letters such as these symbols in a web form?
>
> Maybe a keyboard mapping? An assitant program?

Several years ago, I configured a [macro](https://www.google.com/search?q=macro%20programs)/[hotkey](https://www.google.com/search?q=hotkey%20programs) program for exactly this purpose. I set up a bunch of keyboard combos as triggers with corresponding paste-character events. That way, I can for example, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to enter a `μ` or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to enter a non-breaking-space.

I have well over 100 of these to simplify entering all kinds of extended characters and have become quiet dependent on them (I don't even remember the character-codes of most of them).

There are countless programs that you can use for this purpose, but a simple option is to use AutoHotKey. The beauty of AHK is that it fully supports Unicode characters (at least for this purpose) unlike a lot of the older (and even newer?) hotkey/macro programs. It is also easier to edit since it is a simple text file (though you can compile the result to be an executable to auto-run in the background). The only thing to note is that you *must* set the script file to use UTF-8 encoding instead of ANSI if you want Unicode characters to work in addition to just extended characters (#128-255).

Here is a small script to get you started:

```
!=  ::Send ≠        ;   Alt + =             =   not-equals (this one just sounds weird)
#X  ::Send Ξ        ;   Win + X             =   capital Xi
^+1 ::Send ¡        ;   Ctrl + Shift + 1    =   inverted exclamation mark
^+4 ::Send ¢        ;   Ctrl + Shift + 4    =   cent symbol
#/  ::Send ‽        ;   Win + /             =   interrobang
#T  ::Send 树        ;   Win + T             =   Chinese character for tree
```

You can set the keys and their [modifiers](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) as desired and only have to copy-paste the characters one final time.

Comment: Come to think of it, the program I use is kind of old and does not support Unicode characters, only extended. Writing up the sample script was so easy, that I think I will spend tonight converting all of my hotkeys to an AHK script. `:-)`

Comment: For the record, I did it. I copied the list of hotkeys from my old macro program and ported it to AHK and added a few more that the macro program did not support. Now I can easily enter any and all Unicode characters easily and don’t even have to release and re-press the modifiers for each one, nor do I have to worry about wiping out the clipboard. Yay! ⇨°≠↕‽…