# Getting some French-Canadian keyboard strokes to work on English keyboard

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I'm trying to use some of the French-Canadian keyboard stokes I'm used to on an English keyboard. I would like to change the behaviour of some keys. I was able to implement these changes in Vim, but I would like them to be applied system-wide (for Windows and Ubuntu).

Here's what I want to implement :

- If I press <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, the character printed is `â`.
- When I press <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, something that's supposed to stay normal, the characters printed are  `[r`.
- If I hold <kbd>[</kbd> for 3 seconds, `[` is printed. I want this delay to be applied to all my modified keys.
- I want to map <kbd><</kbd> to `'` and the characters <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to `è`.

  The *complex problem* here is that I only want the <kbd>'</kbd> beside the <kbd>;</kbd> key to produce the `è` character, **NOT** when I press the <kbd><</kbd> (remapped to `'`) then <kbd>e</kbd>.

I'll show you a .vimrc file that implements this, now I want this behavior system-wide:

```
set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
inoremap [a â
inoremap [A Â
inoremap [e ê
inoremap [E Ê
inoremap [i î
inoremap [I Î
inoremap [o ô
inoremap [O Ô
inoremap [u û
inoremap [U Û

inoremap 'a à
inoremap 'A À
inoremap 'e è
inoremap 'E È
inoremap 'u ù
inoremap 'U Ù

inoremap }e ë
inoremap }E Ë
inoremap }i ï
inoremap }I Ï
inoremap }u ü
inoremap }U Ü

inoremap ]c ç
inoremap ]C Ç
inoremap / é
inoremap < '
```

Comment: Why not simply switch to a fr-CA keyboard?

Comment: I find the English keyboard to be easier to use for keys like `[`, `{`, `"`, `@`, etc. when I'm writing code for example. I always need to erase because I didn't switch keyboard and it's frustrating.

Comment: Aren’t French letters available on the US-international keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but accents are not at the same place as on a French-Canadian keyboard. They're even very hard to type fast. Example : à is typed with `\``, then `a`. You can't keep a good typing flow if you have to type those two characters.

Comment: [What are you really trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/171857)

Comment: I want to use an English keyboard and be able to type French accents as I'm used to without having to constantly switch between keyboards. On my French keyboard, I can type `[` (which is a dead key) followed by `e` to get `ê`. I want to keep that behaviour without losing the `[` key.

Comment: Why don't you just set a shortcut to switch between keyboards? You can then switch into the french layout when needed and switch back when done. I regularly do this switching between English (us), Spanish and Greek layouts.

Comment: I find it inconvenient to type `\section{Maïs, père}` on a French and on an English keyboard and I hate having to switch keyboard twice simply to write those 19 characters. I'll rephrase my question : Is there a tool I can use to create dead keys on an English keyboard and which only last a couple of seconds when pressed?

Comment: `My question is rather complex.` The make it simpler, introducing your question like that won't make anyone put in the effort to answer it any time soon.

Comment: If all you really want to do is to simplify entering accented characters on an English keyboard, then do you *really* need the whole dead-character thing? Would simply holding modifiers suffice? (e.g., pressing `Ctrl+Win+A`=`á`, `Ctrl+Win+Shift+A`=`Á`, `Win+Alt+A`=`à`, `Win+Alt+Shift+A`=`À`…)

Comment: Well Gradient has not responded, but [here’s what I did](http://superuser.com/a/447238/3279) to make it super easy and convenient to enter any Unicode characters I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), mentioned by harrymc, was the solution.

Here is a part of the AutoHotKey code that solves my specific problem. Missing letters can be easily added.

```
StringCaseSense On

; circumflex accents
$[::
Send [
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if Char = a
{
    Send {backspace}â
    return
}
Send %Char%
return

; grave accents
$'::
Send '
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if Char = a
{
    Send {backspace}à
    return
}
Send %Char%
return

; trema
+]::
Send {}}
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if Char = e
{
    Send {backspace}ë
    return
}
Send %Char%
return

; cedilla
$]::
Send ]
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if Char = c
{
    Send {backspace}ç
    return
}
Send %Char%
return

; other fixes
$<::
Send '
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if Char =
{
    Send {backspace}<
    return
}
Send %Char%
return

$/::
Send é
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if (Char = "")
{
    Send {backspace}/
    return
}
Send %Char%
return

$?::
Send É
Input, Char, T2 L1, {delete}{esc}{home}{end}
if (Char = "")
{
    Send {backspace}?
    return
}
Send %Char%
return
```

Comment: Nice work. You should have gotten the bounty because you actually showed *how* to implement it by providing an *actual script* instead of just a generic, figure-it-out-for-yourself link. I was going to write a script like this, but you already had it done. +1

Answer (score 3):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (AHK) can do all of this and much more, but is only available for Windows,
which is where I have experience with this wonderful macro recorder that has grown
into a complete programming environment.

For Linux, there is a cross platform version that runs AHK on Linux under .NET or MONO: [IronAHK](http://www.ironahk.net/),
but I have no experience with it.

The article [Install IronAHK on Linux](http://www.inductiveload.com/posts/install-ironahk-on-linux/) might be useful.

Comment: Nice to hear there's an AHK for Linux.